# ReactJS add multiple input fields dynamically

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am new to React and am lost at trying to figure out how to add input field dynamically with React.
 If someone can please help me in figuring out how to bind an onclick to add another field dynamically to the form.
 How can i click add button and another option input will render

```
class AddPost extends Component {
    static contextTypes = {
            router: React.PropTypes.object
};

    appendInput() {
        var newInput = `input-${this.state.inputs.length}`;
        this.setState({ inputs: this.state.inputs.concat([newInput]) });
    }

handleFormSubmit(formProps){
this.props.addPost(formProps);
this.context.router.push('/posts');
}
    render(){
      const {handleSubmit,fields:{title,option}} = this.props;
        return (
          <div className="row top-buffer">
          <div className="col md-auto">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
                <fieldset className="form-group">
                  <label>Question:</label>
                  <input {...title} className="form-control" placeholder="Enter question here"/>
                  {title.touched && title.error && <div className="text-danger">{title.error}</div>}
                  </fieldset>
                <fieldset className="form-group">
                  <label>Option:</label>
                  <input {...option} className="form-control" placeholder="Enter option"/>
                  {option.touched && option.error && <div className="text-danger">{option.error}</div>}
                </fieldset>
                    <fieldset className="form-group">
                        <label>Option:</label>
                        <input {...option} className="form-control" placeholder="Enter option"/>
                        {option.touched && option.error && <div className="text-danger">{option.error}</div>}
                    </fieldset>
                 <button className="btn btn-success">Add</button>
                </form>
              <button onClick={ () => this.appendInput() }>
                  CLICK ME TO ADD AN INPUT
              </button>
          </div>
          </div>
        );

    }

}

function validate(formProps){
const errors = {};
if(! formProps.title){
 errors.title = "Title is required";   
}
if(! formProps.option){
    errors.body = "Option is required";
}
return errors;
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    posts:state.post
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
form:'post',
fields:['title','body'],
validate:validate,
},mapStateToProps,{addPost})(AddPost);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form). Checkout the example with [FieldArray](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.7/examples/fieldArrays/), that should help.

Comment: Hi what if i am not using redux? can this still be implemented without redux?